# count for association table using Sequelize with MSSQL

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I need to take the count of association table. I use Sequelize with MSSQL.
**Tried Code**

```
[Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("Members.id")), "usersCount"],
```

**Error message**

```
{"level":"error","message":{"error":"SequelizeDatabaseError: The multi-part identifier \"ProjectCodeName.Code\" could not be bound.","path":"","service":"PROJECTSERVICE_PROJECTLIST"}}
```

I need to use Sequelize's count method as above for the association table without using raw query (select COUNT...).
Kindly suggest.